# Gain access to my SD card slot on macOS mojave

Tags: windows-7, sd-card

As said above newer macOS do not grant admin access to the SD card slot,
what I would want to do is install WINDOWS 7 on it, But on stem 3.2 I get VERR_ACCESS_DENIED,
because of this:

MacBook-Pro-di-Matteo:~ Matteo$ id
uid=501(Matteo) gid=20(staff) groups=20(staff),701(com.apple.sharepoint.group.1),... and so on

MacBook-Pro-di-Matteo:~ Matteo$ ls -l /dev/disk3
brw-r-----  1 root  operator    1,   8 13 Mar 16:46 /dev/disk3

Where /dev/disk3 is the SDcard slot,
How could i gain access in order to execute step3.2?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Select the Drive itself, mounted on the Desktop; Get Info & check the box for "Ignore ownership on this volume".

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there Is no ignore ownership box on the get info Tab, It says i have personalized access, but It won't per me RAW access the hard drive

Comment: Ignore ownership should be an option on all drives except the current boot drive. What format is the card? FAT won't show ignore ownership because it doesn't actually support it, but that would mean the only way to lock it would be to flip the switch on the physical card. NTFS won't write because it's not natively supported - you need a 3rd party utility.

Comment: It's actually MS-DOS (FAT32).

Comment: The command that fails is:   MacBook-Pro-di-Matteo:~ Matteo$ sudo VBoxManage internalcommands createrawvmdk -filename bootcamp.vmdk -rawdisk /dev/disk3
VBoxManage: error: Cannot open the raw disk '/dev/disk3': VERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND
VBoxManage: error: The raw disk vmdk file was not created

Comment: What do you mean by flipping the switch on the physical card? Is it possible?

Comment: By third party utility you mean i should perform this on windows? I am sorry i don't know how to hit enter without sending the comment

Comment: SD cards have a write lock switch on the side. It's interpreted in software onlt, but can prevent write. You never mentioned VBox before & I'm afraid I have no clue how it works or what it needs. You mention instructions, but not what they are. …and don't hit Enter unless you want to send; comments have no paragraphs. You can edit them afterwards for about 4 mins, but that's about it.